# Is there any physical meaning to the arclength of a position/time graph?

Tags: kinematics, spacetime, metric-tensor

Does it mean anything physically relevant if you take the arclength of a position time graph or a velocity time graph? Does it actually tell you the total position traveled along the entire curve, or is it some completely arcane result that has no meaning, like the integral of a position/time graph ?

For instance, the theory of relativity uses arc-length for worldlines to calculate proper time, but what is an arclength operator doing on any distance/time interval that accounts not only for worldlines, but for other physical interpretations as well?

Comment: Do you think that's the same circumstance as the arclength of a function like y=ax^2+bx+c?

Comment: +1 My apologies  that I mislead you, but can I suggest, and  not just  because I was asleep at the wheel here, that you include the relativity tag (and possibly more tags ) and change references to  distance  to intervals where necesary. Best of luck with it.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't mean anything, because the axes have different units, so the computation of arc length doesn't make sense. The arc length would be $\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta t^2}$, but the two terms have different units, so you can't add them.

Comment: But on the other hand, you special relativity uses arclength https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line

Comment: In theory of relativity, arc length of timelike curves (world lines) is the proper time elapsed along the world line https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length. One axis is space, the other is time, and it seems to make sense, and it seems to work.

Comment: @DaneJoe Sure, in Relativity space and time use the same dimension (in the dimension analysis sense): spacetime; so they can be added together. In classical physics they are different dimensions.

Comment: @rodrigo In relativity space and time are still separate dimensions, it is only that time is recognized  as a n average dimensions like any other that makes it any different. Positon/time graphs also aren't limited to classical physics scenarios either, they can welcome any physics like with a lorentz boost, so you could convert meters to seconds or seconds to meters if that helps make a case.

Comment: @DaneJoe $\Delta x^2+\Delta t^2$ makes sense in relativity because time is being measured in meters (or space is being measured in seconds).

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy "time is measured in meters" that's not necessarily relevant because in both instances, time is still its own dimension. What does arclength do in general to a function on a position/time or velocity/time graph that not only account for worldlines, but other physical interpretations? Like for instance, I could say "subtracting the input of a function by a constant generally shifts it into the future as it represents a delay, such as when you go from x=at^2 x=a(t-2s)^2" which is a mathematical transformation that has the same general meaning in different areas of physics.

Comment: @DaneJoe: We are using the word _dimension_ with two different unrelated meanings here, and that is confusing. Space and time are different _dimensions_ in the sense of four-dimension space, but they both use the same _dimension_ in the sense that they can be measured using the same units. In Classical Physics meters and seconds are different units and cannot be mixed, but in Relativity one meter is just $1 \over c$ of a second, so they can be added (think in [Natural Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units)).

Comment: @rodrigo Any dimension "can" arbitrarily be chosen to be counted in the same units or different units. But in terms of the actual vector space we use to define dimensions, they're both just numbers on a line regardless.

Comment: @DaneJoe: I don't agree. In Mathematics they're both just numbers and you can operate however you want. But in Physics they are _physical quantities_, so they are numbers with dimension (units) and you must follow certain rules. Take a look at [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).

Comment: @rodrigo In physics you choose how you represent the system to best model it, dimensional analysis isn't going to answer anything relevant here we're doing simple cross multiplication.

Comment: or not doing it*

Comment: @DaneJoe: Sorry, but I don't understand what cross multiplication has to do with anything. When you compute the length of a position/time curve you are adding position plus time, as this answer clearly states. And dimensional analysis says that you cannot do that unless your model treats these two dimensions as equivalent. Relativity does; classical mechanics does not.

Answer (score 1):

One must specify a metric to measure an arc-length.

If you use the Galilean metric, $$ds^2=dt^2$$, to measure the arc-length, then you have the Galilean proper time along that worldline. So, when various worldlines start at event A and end at event B, you find that all worldline segments from A to B have the same Galilean proper time. This is "absolute time."

(For special relativity, you of course use a different metric, e.g. $$ds^2=dt^2-(dx/c)^2$$, to get the special-relativistic proper time.... which then displays the clock effect.)

Comment: Okay but you realize this is not limited to wordlines right? That's just one single example of where it happens to work. How does it work in general? Specifically, what transformation or unit is it physically representing on a graph not only to make it work for a wordline but for other things as well?

Comment: This metric [sometimes called the temporal metric] applies to all curves in a Galilean spacetime. It adds up the time-components of all segments of the curve, yielding the elapsed-time between its endpoints [and which is "absolute", independent of the spacetime-path between the events and independent of the observer making the measurement].  For a segment that is "spacelike", that segment has zero length with this metric. One can assign a length to such a segment using the spatial metric of Galilean spacetime $dL^2=dx^2$... two metrics are needed because the Galilean metric is degenerate.

Comment: The "Galilean spacetime" is developed, for example, 
in a book by I.M. Yaglom "A Simple Noneuclidean Geometry and its Physical Basis". https://archive.org/details/ASimpleNon-euclideanGeometryAndItsPhysicalBasis

Comment: A Galilean metric was replaced with the more accurate  model used in the theory of relativity. What im looking for is the commonalities across different interpretations. So by inference of what you're suggesting, because you didn't  explain further, all arclengths on all position time graphs always yield time, just like how all integrals on all velocity time graphs yield position.

Comment: Spacetime arc-length $ds^2=dt^2-k(dx/c)^2$ applied to timeline curves gives elapsed proper time... k=1 for special relativity and k=0 for Galilean. Note that arc-length $\int ds$ is not the same kind of quantity as as the "area under the curve" $\int v dt$.

Comment: I prefer a time-dominant description for relativity because I value causality. Some others, however, prefer a space-dominant description... in that case, one could measure spatial lengths and use a metric like $ds^2=dx^2-(c dt)^2$ for special relativity and $ds^2=dx^2$ for Galilean relativity [supplemented with $dT^2=dt^2$].